# Storing live TestNG Data

Tags: java, selenium, server, testng, storage

I'm looking for a solution to the following:

Basically I am running automated tests using Selenium & TestNG, I have a report set up and a monitor set up ( A HTML file that I can view to see the progress of my tests. ) When a test is passed/failed/skipped it gets amended to the HTML file until the suite is finished.

When the project is fully finished and implemented, I want to run the tests outside of work hours for various reasons.

Therefore what I want to achieve is a mobile application where I can log in and view my tests progress.

To achieve this ( well from the plan I have taught up, someone else might be able to point me in a better direction ) I plan on finding a way to host results on a webserver which can then be accessed by the mobile application and convert these results into something viewable on the front end of the mobile application. The time accucary might not be a 100% with this method as the time it will take from the results to go from TestNG to the server to the mobile application but once its within reason it should be OK.

[image: flowchart]

So the question is how can I store a live feed of my TestNG results on a webserver? Or even locally at the moment just for testing purposes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would log your results to the db of your choice and then create a mobile friendly webpage that queries the db and summarizes the run.

If that's too much work, can you not just post your HTML file to a webserver that you have access to from your mobile device?

Comment: Hi @JeffC thanks for the answer I will give that a go. I could make it simple but I wanna do something similar/bigger for my final year college project so the more research/hard work I can on summer holidays the more knowledge I will have for my college return :)

Comment: Definitely. You might do a v1 that gets the job done and then plan and work on a v2 which is more flexible, cooler, etc. but takes more work.

Comment: Have you any recommendations on technologies I could use? I currently have XAMPP installed on the webserver, could I use the database with XAMPP? Also in terms of summarizing the run, is it possible to query the Database as it is being updated? To give the mobile app a live results of the tests as they are being executed rather than when they are finished executing? Thanks @JeffC

Comment: I'm not familiar with XAMPP, sorry. Generally I would just query the database on page refresh that way you always have the most recent results. You could set the page to refresh every X minutes so that you don't have to keep hitting refresh on the browser. Depending on how long your tests are, you might want to refresh more or less often. You could go crazy and use AJAX to refresh the results. You could go even crazier and background query the db so that it only refreshes when new results are available. I would just go with the simple refresh every X minutes myself but it's up to you. :)

Comment: thank you so much, that information is hugely useful ! I will give it a go, keep it quite simple and as I progress I can work on it more and more. Thanks again Jeff !